# grid view find last row when we do paging in c#.net

Tags: c#, gridview, paging

I have approximate 50000 row gridview.and i set the pagesize 20  grid view.so how we can find the last row  gridview.If we do  next then it takes more time.

Comment: Do you mean the last on the current page, or the last record in the total record set?

Comment: last on the current page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, you want to shift to last page from first page.
What you can do is when you are binding the `gridview` save number of rows in your data source in `viewstate`:

```
viewstate["rowCount"]=number;
```

Then use a seperate link for navigating to last page
which fires pageindexchanging event. On that event you can calculate `Viewstate["rowCount"]/pagesize`which will give you total pages.

Now assign `gridview.pageIndex=aboveresult`

Answer (score 0):

You can also

```
int RowCount = GridView.Rows.Count;
GridView.PageIndex = RowCount/20;//as you set 20 rows per page...
```